# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to use Dropdownlist in my MVC project but this error occur :

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key Id

My Controller is

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {

        ViewData["CourseId"] = new SelectList(reg.tbl_Course, "Id", "Course");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register( tbl_User user)
    {
        reg.tbl_User.Add(user);
        reg.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }
```

and my i use this code for Dropdownlist in my view

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId",null , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

i use ViewBag and ViewData , but i see the same error.
please Help Me

Comment: how does your object `reg.tbl_Course` look like?

Comment: I have a dataBase that contains two table , table course and table user. course contains two column id and course and table user have name and family and idcourse that is foreign key

Comment: @hamed this is not enough, could you please add `reg.tbl_Course` class and properties?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Model that looks like:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var listOfCourses = new List<CourseViewModel>()
    {
        new CourseViewModel() {Id = 1, Course = "Course Name 1"},
        new CourseViewModel() {Id = 2, Course = "Course Name 2"},
    };

    ViewData["CourseId"] = new SelectList(listOfCourses, "Id", "Course");

    return View();
}
```

in you `.cshtml` simply use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CourseId")
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Then you need to provide more information. Something like a stacktrace would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think your error says that view data needs to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Try something like in controller:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();//gets db context
List<SelectListItem> users = new List<SelectListItem>();//creating list of select list items
var userList = db.Users.ToList();//geting list of users
foreach (var user in userList)
{
    users.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = user.Id, Text = user.UserName});//populating select list with items
}
ViewData.Add("ApplicationUserId",users.AsEnumerable());//adding list to view data
return View();
```

And in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ApplicationUserId, null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```